# How to delete an attachment on outlook 365 when deleting fails

Tags: google-chrome, outlook-web-access

I'm getting the following error message:

`The following attachments couldn't be deleted: my_document.docx. Please try again later.`

This appears to be happening for all my attached documents (currently all docx files).

I'm on Windows 10 using Chrome. I tried logging out, clearing all related cookies and data, and logging in, but the problem has persisted. What's causing this problem and how do I delete the attachments?

Comment: Have you tried other browsers like Edge or IE?

Comment: I just tried Firefox and Edge, both give the same error.

Comment: How about testing on another machine?